# bash --> perl command: print only the replaced text

Tags: bash, perl, regex

I have the file "test.txt" that contains:

```
Val1 = '59'
Val2 = '76'
Val3 = '42'
Val4 = '53'
```

I with this command:

```
perl -pe "s/^Val2 = '(.*)'/\1/" test.txt
```

I Want:

```
76
```

But I obtain:

```
Val1 = '59'
76
Val3 = '42'
Val4 = '53'
```

Comment: You will get more responses if you post on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of this stack. The questions on coding with tags [perl] and [regex] get many in-depth responses there.

Comment: Ah, ok. I use also that but I mistakenly thought that this, being Ubuntu specific, was the most appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-p` argument is like sed's default print - also like sed, if you want to suppress default print, you would use `-n` instead.

So you could do

```
perl -ne "print if s/^Val2 = '(.*)'/\1/" test.txt
```

You could also use a regex *match* rather than a regex *substitute*:

```
perl -lne "print \$1 if /^Val2 = '(.*)'/" test.txt
```

or

```
perl -nE "say \$1 if /^Val2 = '(.*)'/" test.txt
```

(the backslash is to protect `$1` from being expanded by the shell, since the expression is in double quotes to allow use of lieral single quotes in the match).

Comment: steeldriver, your second solution sounds the best of the three and also better of Timur answer because while "if" returns only first parameter, the for loop returns all eventual parameters separated by newlines. However Timur rightly suggested to me not to force the spaces to only one, even if, as usual, you have more strictly adhered to my question.

Comment: Re: "the [script] is in double quotes to allow use of lieral single quotes in the match": Note that, to put the script in single-quotes, you can write `perl -nE 'say $1 if /^Val2 = \x27(.*)\x27/' test.txt`. It's generally safer to put the script in single-quotes and replace `'` where necessary, than to put it in double-quotes and try to remember all the different things that need to be escaped in double-quotes (namely dollar signs, backticks, exclamation marks, double-quotes, and backslashes . . . and I'm not even sure that's a complete list).

Answer (score 3):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne "print for /^Val2\s+=\s+'(.*)'/" test.txt
```

It is slightly shorter and there is not need to escape any variables, since the `for` loop passes the captured group `(.*)` to `print` implicitly as `$_`, which is the default argument to `print`.

It also uses "`\s+`" (1 or more whitespace characters) instead of " " (1 blank) to be less strict about the input it accepts. While optional, I prefer to follow the rule about being less strict on the input, and more strict on the output (not sure about the source of this rule, though).

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: I was very undecided on which was the best answer, but by dint of tests and reasoning, I opted for the second among those of steeldriver even if I fully accepted your suggestion regarding spaces and I preferred to use "\s*" rather than "\s+". Also read my comment under the @steeldriver answer. In any case, thank you both very much.